# What is variable arg referring to in this function? Flow of arguments in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is an answer to a SO question:

```
function typedFunction(paramsList, f){
    //optionally, ensure that typedFunction is being called properly  -- here's a start:
    if (!(paramsList instanceof Array)) throw Error('invalid argument: paramsList must be an array');

    //the type-checked function
    return function(){
        for(var i=0,p,arg;p=paramsList[i],arg=arguments[i],i<paramsList.length; i++){
            if (typeof p === 'string'){
                if (typeof arg !== p) throw new Error('expected type ' + p + ', got ' + typeof arg);
            }
            else { //function
                if (!(arg instanceof p)) throw new Error('expected type ' + String(p).replace(/\s*\{.*/, '') + ', got ' + typeof arg);
            }
        }
        //type checking passed; call the function itself
        return f.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

//usage:
var ds = typedFunction([Date, 'string'], function(d, s){
    console.log(d.toDateString(), s.substr(0));
});

ds('notadate', 'test');
//Error: expected type function Date(), got string
ds();
//Error: expected type function Date(), got undefined
ds(new Date(), 42);
//Error: expected type string, got number
ds(new Date(), 'success');
//Fri Jun 14 2013 success
```

It shows a generalized way of ensuring arguments conform to specified types. I am having a hard time grasping the flow of arguments from the `ds` function call, back to the function that is returned from `typedFunction()`.

**Here's what I expect:**

- `paramsList` should refer to the first parameter in `typedFunction()`'s function
- `arguments` should refer to a list of all arguments passed to `typedFunction`, in this case both `paramsList` and `f`. However, it seems like `arguments` refers to the arguments passed in `ds`. That's where things get fuzzy. How do the arguments supplied in `ds` get passed to `f`?

### Could you explain the logical flow of events/ how this code works?

Sorry if the question is not clear. Please edit the question if you have a grasp of what I'm trying to ask and can make the question easier to read.

Comment: the `arg` variable is used to iterate through the returned function's `arguments` ... `ds` is the result of calling `typedFunctions`, the result being the function I referred to earlier

Comment: @JaromandaX correct, so shouldn't arg refer to `paramsList` and `f`?

Comment: @GovindRai—no. The returned function has a closure to *paramsList* as passed to the initial function.

Comment: No, `ds` is the result of calling `typedFunctions`, the result being the function I referred to earlier, it's when calling ds() that the code that iterates through the parameters is executed

Comment: @RobG I apparently missed the entire lesson on closures.. there's a good link in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of explanation, assume we name the function being returned as `typeChecker`:

```
function typedFunction(paramsList, f){
    // ...
    return function typeChecker() { ... }
}
```

Now, here's the rundown of what is happening:

Running

```
var ds = typedFunction([Date, 'string'], function(d, s){
    console.log(d.toDateString(), s.substr(0));
});
```

binds `[Date, 'string']` as `paramsList` and `function(d, s) { ... }` as `f` in the outer environment ([closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)) of `typeChecker`. This means `typeChecker` will, when called, have access to this data via the specified bound variable names `paramsList` and `f`.

Then we run:

```
ds(new Date(), 'success');
```

which essentially runs `typeChecker(new Date(), 'success')`.

Side note: within any normal JS function ([arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) behaves differently), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is a special array-like object provided when the function is called. This object contains all the arguments passed into the function, irrelevant of how many parameters are specified in the function signature.

This means that, when we invoke `ds(new Date(), 'success')`, `arguments` conceptually looks like this:

```
[dateInstance, 'success']
```

although technically, it looks more like this:

```
{
  0: dateInstance,
  1: 'success'
}
```

but this makes no difference in the given code since both structures provide numeric property/index access being used in the `for` loop.

Therefore, inside `typeChecker`, `arg` will refer to the item at the corresponding index in the `arguments` object for each loop iteration, i.e. `arg=arguments[i]`.

Once the iteration is finished, this runs:

```
return f.apply(this, arguments);
```

which calls the function initially given to `typedFunction` as its second parameter, the one that was bound to the name `f` in `typeChecker`'s closure, supplying [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) as the `this` from within `typeChecker` and passing along arguments from `typeChecker`.

Comment: +1 for constant edits and I appreciate that `closure link`. This makes a lot more sense. Just out of curiosity, `f.apply(this, arg);` would work too then, correct?

Comment: No, it can't. `arg` refers to a single argument, whereas we need to supply all arguments at the end. Thanks again.

Comment: @GovindRai You're welcome :). And yup, `arg` is just one of the arguments, the behavior would be different.